# Пытаюсь написать безопасную аутентификацию php + js, где найти стандарты и/или актуальные рекомендации?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, аутентификация, стандарт, best-practice

В частности, не могу найти информацию о том, как защитить данные об авторизации, хранящиеся на стороне клиента, от перехвата злоумышленником. Поиск в гугле выдает в основном гайды и страницы форума, которые содержат противоречивую и часто устаревшую информацию.

Comment: От перехвата полностью защищает HTTPS, вот и всё

Comment: @andreymal Зато HTTPS не защищает данные от перехвата хостером.

Comment: @DiD ну от него уже не защитит ничего, кроме своего собственного сервера в своём собственном помещении (да и то не факт, что в аппаратной части сервера нет каких-нибудь закладок...)

Comment: @andreymal напрасно вы так думаете, в наше время всяких мэш-сетей хостить может кто-угодно, что угодно. И с хорошо зашифрованной информацией хостер не сможет сделать ничего. Яркий пример тому - mega.nz. Файлы шифруются на стороне клиента, ключ на сервер не посылается.

Comment: @DiD это всё конечно хорошо, но к сути данного вопроса имеет отношение примерно никакое

Comment: @andreymal согласен, человек пытается защитить от перехвата куки на стороне браузера.

Comment: @andreymal  То есть, если запретить доступ по http, то можно хранить данные в local storage , например, и не беспокоиться по данному поводу?

Comment: @elina если злоумышленник каким-то образом получит полный доступ к компьютеру пользователя, то он и любой local storage и любые cookies сможет прочитать в любое время, и никакой https тут уже не поможет. Но это как бы уже и не перехват вообще-то (ну или мы вкладываем разный смысл в слово «перехват»)

Comment: @elina ответ вытекает из самого вопроса - не храните данные авторизации на стороне клиента и у Вас не будет проблем. Если же все же нужно - установите на стороне клиента маленькое время жизни `cookie` или генерируйте ее по принципу `отпечаток пользователя`, чтобы смена `IP`, `browser`, `browser plugins` и тд. (из той информации, что Вы еще сможете собрать о клиенте)  изменяла значение `cookie`.